# ¿Por qué en el momento de asignar un modelo a un List de SwiftUI, genera error sin descripción en el View del body?

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy empezando con SwiftUI y realizando una prueba con PokeAPI me sale un Bug sin descripción,d ejo imagen con el error al momento de asignarlo a el List en el ContentView, dejo el modelo y la clase.

**Modelo**

```
struct Pokemon: Hashable, Codable {
    var name: String
    var front_default: String
    var front_default_art: String
}
```

**Código**

```
func loadData(completion: @escaping([Pokemon]) -> ()) {
        let url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=151&offset=0"
        guard let urlObj = URL(string: url) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj) {(data, response, errpor) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let pokedex = try JSONDecoder().decode(Pokedex.self, from: data)
                
                for pokemon in pokedex.results {
                    guard let jsonUrl = pokemon.url else { return }
                    guard let newUrl = URL(string: jsonUrl) else { return }
                    
                    
                    var request = URLRequest(url: newUrl)
                    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
                        guard let data = data else { return }
                        
                        do {
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
                            
                            guard let name = json["name"] as? String else { return }
                            guard let _ = json["height"] as? Int else { return }
                            print(name)
                            guard let sprites = json["sprites"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> else { return }
                            guard let front_default = sprites["front_default"] as? String else { return }
                            print(front_default)
                            
                            guard let other = sprites["other"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> else { return }
                            guard let official_artwork = other["official-artwork"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> else { return }
                            guard let front_default_art = official_artwork["front_default"] as? String else { return }
                            print(front_default_art)
                            
                            let aja = Pokemon(name: name, front_default: front_default, front_default_art: front_default_art)
                            self.pokemons.append(aja)
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                completion(self.pokemons)
                            }
                        } catch let jsonErr {
                            print("Error json responde: ", jsonErr)
                        }
                    }.resume()
                }
                
            } catch let err {
                print("Error: responde Api: ", err)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Hola, te invito a que hagas el recorrido del sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para leer sobre cómo hacer preguntas. Y de paso conseguir tu primer medalla. No agregues el código con imágenes, agregalo como texto, de esta forma es más facil  tratar de reproducir el error.

Comment: Cómo tienes el modelo? Agrégale como texto como te dicen en el comentario.

Comment: Ya he editado la publicación, soy nuevo usando Stack Overflow, pero gracias por los comentarios y sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

En *SwiftUI* al trabajar con `List` debes establecer un identificador único al modelo; es decir que tu `Struct` o `Class` debe tener un identificador `id` y heredar de un nuevo protocolo llamado:

```
protocol Identifiable
```

Según la documentación de Apple [aquí](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable) dice que:

> Utilice el protocolo identificable para proporcionar una noción estable de identidad a una clase o tipo de valor. Por ejemplo, puede definir un tipo de usuario con una propiedad id que sea estable en su aplicación y en el almacenamiento de la base de datos de su aplicación. Puede usar la propiedad id para identificar a un usuario en particular incluso si cambian otros campos de datos, como el nombre del usuario.

Para solucionar el error agregas el protocolo:

```
struct Pokemon: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var front_default: String
    var front_default_art: String
}
```

De esta forma la Lista sabe que cada valor del modelo es único y lo puede agregar en cada celda.